# How to check that DNS hijacking happened in next.js?

Tags: next.js

In my next.js website I want to show a UI alert to an end user if DNS hijacking happened and client side code was modified by the attacker.

So the idea is the following:

1. On website build add "UI hash" of the project build somewhere in js.
2. On website load calculate "UI hash" and compare with the one provided from the build. If they are not equal then show alert like "Phishing attempt".

I understand that this UI check can be easily bypassed by the attacker with enough reverse engineering efforts.

Are there any better ways to prevent DNS hijacking on the UI side?

Comment: You are reinventing something that exists: https://www.w3.org/TR/SRI/ + https://caniuse.com/subresource-integrity ; Do note that this guards against far more things than just DNS hijacking.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thank you. Yes, SRI helps when 3rd party script was modified but in case of DNS hijacking the attacker would have full access to the site so he will be able to modify everything.

Comment: " attacker would have full access to the site so he will be able to modify everything." In which case there is nothing you can do on browser side, because the browser just executes what come from the site, so if anything can be changed, so can be your verification routines.